# How do I query using GQL to find a Column/Entity with duplicate values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have an Entity in the Google Cloud Datastore named `Entity_Name`. How would I query using GQL to find duplicate values among them? GQL does not allow me to do a `GROUP BY` operation.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference)**:

> **GQL maps roughly to SQL: you can think of a GQL kind as a SQL table, a GQL entity as a SQL row, and a GQL property as a SQL column. However, a SQL row-column lookup is limited to a single value, whereas in GQL a property can be a multiple value property.**

Therefore, GQL is *not* the same as SQL. Only the following option **[SELECT clauses are recognized](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#clauses)**:

- DISTINCT
- DISTINCT ON
- FROM
- WHERE
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT
- OFFSET

If you need to find duplicate values in Datastore, **[Find duplicates in App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798858/find-duplicates-in-app-engine-datastore)** shows you a way to do so.